# How to ping ipv6 addresses in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ipv6

How is possible to ping ipv6 address and get respond in Ruby? Net/ping works just with ipv4 addresses.

```
require 'net/ping'

Net::Ping::External.new('ipv6.google.com')
```

Comment: What OS are you on? You can always rely on the OS to do it using `%x` or backticks, or by Open3 or a number of other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a `ping6` method in the latest version of the gem that is for ipv6 but I could not get it to work for your URL.

See https://github.com/chernesk/net-ping/commit/3f2f44b7460628e0d9d49bce2343ffb2fa77cd7d

> Added a new ping6 method in both external.rb and ping.rb. This is a close copy of the current 'ping' method logic in both of these
>   classes, the only difference being that it calls the system ping6
>   command.
>
> This allows the class to be used to ping ipv6 addresses.

```
irb(main):001:0> require 'net/ping'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> Net::Ping::External.new('ipv6.google.com').ping6
=> false
```

This might give you more to go on.